# is there a way to adjust an already defined margin of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have some elements, on hover i want to **adjust** their margin-left slightly, however these elements already have their own different predefined margin-lefts (so i want to keep the already defined margins, but only adjust them, but the cascading nature of css does not allow this)

It would be nice if this can be done in css however if not, using an eventListener is probably the best way, i tried doing something like

```js
card.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
  event.target.style.marginLeft = event.target.style.marginLeft - 25 + "px";
})
```

```css
.parent>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.elem1 {
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.elem2 {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.parent>div:hover {
  margin-left: -25px;
  /* i want this to only adjust the margin */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="elem1"></div>
  <div class="elem2"></div>
  <div class="elem3"></div>
</div>
```

however this does not seem to work, Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: If you're defining the left margin in CSS then the value style.marginLeft won't be defined. Use window.getComputedStyle instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: Can you add your CSS and HTML too. It's likely this can be done only in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

please try this provide your new margins value to hover

```
.elem1:hover{
       margin-left:-75px; //you adjust it according to your needs
}
.elem2:hover{
       margin-left:175px;
}
```

You can also try this if there is many elements:-
check if it is working or not and let me know

```
.parent > div:hover {
  margin-left: calc(margin-left - 25px);
}
```

just do like that hope this will help you ..

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: sir i m not able to comment so thats why i do this i hope you understand !!

Comment: Ok. No worries. It might get downvoted (not by me btw) but just so you know.

Comment: ok sir i am removing it

Comment: edited original post to include more code

Comment: yeah i will provide answer wait

Comment: yeah, im looking for something like the second code segment, but that does not work for me sadly

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use :hover on the element in css and then change the values of width and margin-left in it

for example:

```
div{
        width: 10px;
        margin-left: 23px;
}
div:hover{
             width: 15px;
             margin-left: 18px;
}
```

Here I used div as an example, Just use your own tag tag and values.

Comment: yes, but i want multiple divs(with different predefined margin-left) to have this hover, so i cant do this (i edited original post to include this

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.getComputedStyle` (detailed in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)) to work out the left margin in pixels and then subtract your intended margin and add it to the element style property. Because the style property has higher [specificity](https://youtu.be/c0kfcP_nD9E) than the css, it overrides it. Use the mouseout to remove it and it defaults to the css value:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  elements.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', doMouseOver);
    element.addEventListener('mouseout', doMouseOut);
  });
}

function doMouseOver(e) {
  const marginLeftShift = -25;
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(e.target);
  const computedMarginLeft = style.marginLeft;
  e.target.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(computedMarginLeft) + marginLeftShift) + 'px';
}

function doMouseOut(e) {
  e.target.style.marginLeft = '';
}
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  width: 50%;
}

#one {
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

#two {
  background-color: pink;
  margin-left: 3rem;
}

#three {
  background-color: coral;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id='one'>One</div>
<div id='two'>Two</div>
<div id='three'>Three</div>
```

You can use the css `transform` property but note that won't affect the width or reflow the other elements.

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  width: 50%;
}

div:hover {
  transform:translateX(-25px);
}

#one {
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

#two {
  background-color: pink;
  margin-left: 3rem;
}

#three {
  background-color: coral;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id='one'>One</div>
<div id='two'>Two</div>
<div id='three'>Three</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code for every element of div

```css
.parent > div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: black;
    }

    .elem1 {
        margin-left: -100px;
    }
    .elem2 {
        margin-left: 200px;
    }
    .parent > div:nth-child(1):hover {
        margin-left:calc(-100px + 25px) /* for the first child of div */
    }
    .parent > div:nth-child(2):hover {
        margin-left:calc(200px - 25px) /* for the Second child of div */
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="elem1"></div>
    <div class="elem2"></div>
    <div class="elem3"></div>
</div>
```